# Writing Content to a Text File with Currying

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, currying

```java
public static Function<String, Function<String, Void>> 
write(BiConsumer<BufferedWriter, String> consumer) {
    return resourcePath -> data ->  {
        if(data != null) {
            try {
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resourcePath));
                consumer.accept(bufferedWriter, data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

I'm trying to write to a text file using the above method by applying the concept of currying. The first lambda expression receives the file path as parameter and the second one takes in a String value that should be written to the text file. The `write` method receives a `BiConsumer` argument because data is written differently depending on the context (appending to the end of the file, replacing a specific line in the file etc.). It can be called like this:

```java
DataAccess.write((bufferedWriter, data) -> {
    // write to file here
}).apply("path").apply("data");
```

I know that I'm not supposed to return `Void` with the `Function` interface. How can I change the method definition so that it can be called in a similar way? If possible, I would still like to apply currying in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that I'm not supposed to return `Void` with the `Function` interface. How can I change the method definition so that it can be called in a similar way?

You can change the return type of `write()` method to `Function<String,Consumer<String>>` (a *Function* producing a *Consumer*). Since you don't need to produce any result, it doesn't make sense to use a *Function*. When you only need to fire an action, it's a job for a `Consumer` implementation.

```
public static Function<String, Consumer<String>>
write(BiConsumer<BufferedWriter, String> consumer) {
    
    return resourcePath -> data ->  {
        if(data != null) {
            try(var bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resourcePath))) {
                consumer.accept(bufferedWriter, data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

*Usage example (*`write().apply().accept()`*):*

```
write((bufferedWriter, data) -> {
    // write to file here
}).apply("path").accept("data");
```

***Sidenote:** always use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure that your resources are properly closed.*